# ¿Como puedo hacer que el usuario pueda elegir cuál elemento quiera modificar de un diccionario en python?

Tags: python

```
listaEstudiantes = [207980080,]
diccionarioEstudiantes = {207910080:["Roberto Jesús","Rojas Jimenez","La isla","robertjr07.rr@itcr.ac.cr"]}
listaDocentes = []
listaCarreras = []
listaCursos = []
listaRecintos =[]
listaAulas = []
listaHorarios = []

opcMenuAdmi = int(input("Digite 1.Administrativo" "2.Operativo" "3.Reportes"))

preguntaEstudiantes = int(input("Desea: 1.Agregar estudiantes 2.Modificar estudiante 3.Eliminar estudiante"))
if preguntaEstudiantes == 1 :
    try:
     Cedula = int(input("Digite la cedula"))
     diccionarioEstudiantes[Cedula]=[]
     listaEstudiantes.append(Cedula)
     print(diccionarioEstudiantes)
    except:
        print("Digte solo cedula")
    nombre = input("Digite nombre ")
    diccionarioEstudiantes[Cedula].append(nombre)
    Apellidos = input("Ingrese apellidos")
    diccionarioEstudiantes[Cedula].append(Apellidos)
    Dirección = input("Ingrese dirección")
    diccionarioEstudiantes[Cedula].append(Dirección)
    correo = input("Ingrese correo")
    correo_split = correo.split("@")
    if correo_split[1] == "itcr.ac.cr":
        diccionarioEstudiantes[Cedula].append(correo)
    print(diccionarioEstudiantes[Cedula])


#Aqui el usuario puede escoger cuál elemento o "estudiante" quiere cambiarle la dirección o correo o lo que sea
elif preguntaEstudiantes == 2 :
```

Comment: Buenas, cuando seleccione la opción 2 puedes mostrar las cédulas que tiene el sistema o simplemente pedirle que ponga la cedula que va a editar. Si tienes una duda más concreta especifica más

Answer (score 0):

```
elif preguntaEstudiantes == 2 :
        print("Listando estudiantes:")
        if len(diccionarioEstudiantes):
            for key in diccionarioEstudiantes:
                print("[ID: {}] {} {} <{}>".format(
                    key,
                    diccionarioEstudiantes[key][0],
                    diccionarioEstudiantes[key][1],
                    diccionarioEstudiantes[key][3],
                ))
            estudiante_a_editar = int(input("Introduzca ID de estudiante a editar"))
            if diccionarioEstudiantes.has_key(estudiante_a_editar):
                #...
        else:
            print("Lista de estudiantes vacía.")
```

Con eso podrás listar los estudiantes para que escojan qué editar.

Sin embargo te insto a varias cosas:

- Escribir el código en inglés, excepto los mensajes, especialmente nombres de variables o al menos evitar el uso de tildes.
- Leer documentación sobre PEP8
- Usar diccionarios en lugar de listas para almacenar los alumnos y otros objetos. Los cuales serían luego accesibles de forma nominal.

Como se puede ver en mi respuesta, ahora necesitas acceder al nombre, apellidos y correo usando el valor del índice (0, 1 , 3) en lugar de usar una clave nominal y claramente legible en el código.
Ejemplo:

```
students_dictionary = {
    207910080: {
        'name': "Roberto Jesús",
        'last_name': "Rojas Jimenez",
        'address': '"La isla"',
        'email': "robertjr07.rr@itcr.ac.cr",
    }
}

for student_id in students_dictionary:
    student_data = students_dictionary.get(student_id)
    print("[ID: {}] {} {} <{}>".format(
        student_id,
        student_data['name'],
        student_data['last_name'],
        student_data['email'],
    ))
```

Con esto, después podrías editar simplemente uno de los campos usando:

```
new_email = str(input('Nueva dirección de correo: '))
## comprobar estructura del contenido...
student_data['email'] = new_email
```